# .htaccess rewrite with special url and IDs digits as parameters

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I built my own mvc model.

Now I want to rewrite following url:

[http://example.com/admin/index.php/Frontend/show?request[id]=24&request[lang]=33](http://example.com/admin/index.php/Frontend/show?request%5Bid%5D=24&request%5Blang%5D=33)

to

http://example.com/24/33/

How is it possible to rewrite that url via .htaccess from root path?

I have tried:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /admin/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ index.php/Frontend/show?request[id]=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ index.php/Frontend/show?request[id]=$1&request[lang]=$2 [L]
```

I get following error:

```
No input file specified.
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Issues:

- You probably only want digits.
- You are missing a final `/`

```
# Good
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/$ index.php/Frontend/show?request[id]=$1&request[lang]=$2 [L]
```

Secondly, this rule is WAY too wide.

```
# Bad
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ index.php/Frontend/show?request[id]=$1 [L]
```

Again, you probably want only digits and a final `/`.

```
# Good
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/$ index.php/Frontend/show?request[id]=$1 [L]
```

Finally, for best practices, use a prefix for a directory you will never use.

```
# Gooder
RewriteRule ^show/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/$ index.php/Frontend/show?request[id]=$1&request[lang]=$2 [L]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I tried the last line of your code, but I still get the error _No input file specified_ (f.e. if I type in the URL `example.com/show/24/33/`)
Is it possible that some apache configuration do not allow me to rewrite?
Maybe it is important to know that my index.php file is under the directory `/admin/` , so my RewriteBase is `/admin/`. My .htaccess is in the root directory.